# Knockout loses binding to internal observables when parent object is set to null

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

This is something I ran across today and was wondering if it's something I am doing wrong or perhaps a bug in Knockout.

Imagine there's 3 different view model states coming from a server:

```
State 1 = { AnObject: { WithString: "SomeText" } }
State 2 = { AnObject: null }
State 3 = { AnObject: { WithString: "DifferentText" } }
```

If I do this:

```
<p data-bind="text: AnObject.WithString"></p>
```

Assuming appropriate Knockout binding, I would expect the text of that element to be "SomeText", then nothing, then "DifferentText" as a update my KO view model through all three states.

What actually happens is the first state works fine (text becomes "SomeText"), then on the second state the text does not change and it seems that the binding is lost altogether because on the third state the text still doesn't change even though there's now a good value to use.

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/zAuDs/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this is an artifact of how the mapping plugin handles updates.

On the first mapping an observable is created for `InternalThing`.

On the second mapping the whole observable is removed from the view model (UI is still bound to it).

On the third mapping a new observable is created for `InternalThing`, which is not bound to the UI.

One option would be to force `Obj` to be observable and use a `with: Obj` around your element.

```
  var ViewModel = function(data) {
      var me = this;
      ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, me);
      me.Obj = ko.observable(me.Obj);   

      return me;
  };
```

Then, bind like:

```
<!-- ko with: Obj -->
<h1 data-bind="text: InternalThing">1</h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bJkKp/

Comment: Interesting. That does work and no one else has offered up an answer. I ended up just changing my model a bit to work around this, but I'll accept this as a good answer.

Comment: Another very useful answer from RPN. Have updated the jsfiddle with working/CDN KO refs and some extra info. http://jsfiddle.net/bJkKp/3/